# Значение выражения "намандрючить чучу"

Tags: значение

Недавно состоялся разговор на тему того, насколько русский язык может быть информативным даже в том случае, если значение слов остаётся нам неясным. Приставки, суффиксы и окончания создают дополнительный контекст, из которого можно сложить представление даже о весьма туманных выражениях.

Для анализа выбрана фраза "щас чучу намандрючу" из передачи "Осторожно, модерн!".

Что можно сказать о планах человека, произнёсшего подобное выражение?
У нас есть глагол и существительное. Отсюда ясно, что автор высказывания собирается сделать что-то (намандрючить) с чем-то (с чучей). При этом выглядит всё так, что объекту, чуче, придаётся некоторое новое состояние "намандрюченность", причём приставка "на-" выражает завершённость действия (с оттенком наполнения).

Стало быть, хотя мы не знаем значения слов в этом выражении, мы уже можем примерно описать содержание планов автора высказывания: некоторую чучу привести в завершённое состояние намандрюченности, то есть в такое состояние, что мандрючить сверх этого будет уже дальше некуда.

Можно ли из этого выражения сделать ещё более конкретные выводы о содержании высказывания, путём рассуждений?

Также любопытно, почему это выражение воспринимается как синоним фразы "начистить репу", ведь ничего в нём не указывает на конкретное значение.